How to add and remove from a list with multiple indexes in flutter
I have a ListView with ,say car issues being generated with ListView.builder.
Each issue has a variant on it. So each issue has a nested ListView.builder to show variants for that issueItem. So I want to implement a logic of adding the issue variants to a list. So basically users click on a variant in a Listview.bulder that uses the index of another Listview.builder (Nested) and it gets added to a list. This bit I have implemented fine. But the problem is where the user wants to remove the variant from the list. How do I possibly correctly pass the second index into a ".remove()" method
